# Having trouble using a variable as a module call trigger

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to have the value of a variable determine what module is called, but I'm having difficulties making Python recognize my line of code as the value of a variable as opposed to the variable name itself.

```
project_type = input('What type of project is this?')
job_title = input('What is the title of the job?')
project_type.title(job_title)
```

Python thinks that my module name is "project_type" but I want the module name to be the value of project_type. I've tried using parenthesis or brackets but that hasn't helped, and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: try `globals()[project_type].title(job_title)`. The `globals()` built-in function will return a dict that lets you access all currently-in-scope objects by their name, as a string

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I've never used global variables before but it definitely seems like I should look into them.

Comment: `globals()` is somewhat of a misnomer - IIRC basically just returns every variable that's currently in-scope, including variables that are local to the function currently being called. `locals()` restricts that to just the variables that have been defined within the current function, and might also work if this code is inside a function instead of at the module level.